# Why is Appium unable to locate elements in a Webview in a native app even after switching contexts?

Tags: ruby, webview, appium, appium-ios

So I'm a relatively new Appium user, so please excuse me if this question seems a little basic.

My company has a hybrid application which uses webiews in several places, and I am currently in the middle of writing test scripts for this application in Ruby using Appium. I've been stuck for a while, because I reach a page where I need to search for elements inside a webview and click on them. So far, I've managed to switch contexts to the webview using

`set_context context_array.last`

and I know that the context switch is successful, because I then output my current context to the terminal, and it correctly outputs that I'm in the webview. I then used Safari to inspect the elements in my webview, and saw the following HTML code:

[HTML Source Code Excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iQgx.png)

I followed the xlink and found the following lines of code:
`<symbol id="icon-eat" viewBox="0 0 58 58">
<title>icon-eat</title>`

So in my Appium script, I've tried to locate the element using the following, which so far haven't worked.
1. `wait { xpath('//symbol[@id="icon-eat"]') }`
2. `wait { id("icon-eat") }`

Any advice on how to proceed? My capabilities are:

```
options = {
  caps:        {
    platformName: 'iOS',
    platformVersion: '10.3',
    deviceName: 'iPhone 7',
    app: APP_PATH,
    automationName: "XCUITest",
    browserName: "iOS",
    startIWDP: true,
    nativeWebTap: true
  },
    launchTimeout: 20000
}
```

An Appium log is attached. I've replaced the company name and other sensitive details for security purposes.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6mwi0KrKYGQTGctek9wWm5ES28/view?usp=sharing